# Sony vaio: install windows 7 without destroying recovery feature

Tags: data-recovery, sony-vaio

I have a sony vaio with windows 8 but I like to install windows 7 from a ISO image.

However, I like to make sure that I don't destroy the recovery feature.

Some details to explain it better:

I can start the PC by pressing the ASSIST button. This gives a menu where I can select a number of things. One is to recover to factory settings. Another is to boot from USB device.

I like to boot from USB device and install windows 7.

But I'm afraid that installing windows 7 will also remove the recovery.

Does anyone know how I can install windows 7 this way and still have the recovery option available if I want to go back to the original windows 8.

EDIT:
I already have recovery DVDs but my  DVD drive stopped working so I can't use them. I don't know if some SW update caused that problem or whether it is simply a HW malfunction.

Comment: Use a third party software to make an Image of the entire hard drive, this image can be restored at a later date if you need W7 again. [I like Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/en-us/personal/computer-backup/) but is not free, [Macrium Reflect has a free version](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The safest thing to do is to create a set of recovery disks (DVDs) for Windows 8.

That way you can always recover Windows 8 using the Recovery Disks without having to worry about the recovery partition.

An additional advantage is that you can use these disks if your hard disk dies and you need to replace it.

To create the Recovery Disks:

1. Run the Sony "VAIO Care" program (you made need to be an Administrator).
2. Click "Recovery" on the left side.
3. Click "Create Recovery Media".

You will need 3 or 4 DVDs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. There is one problem I didn't mention - the DVD drive is not working. I already have recovery DVDs but can't use them as the DVD drive stopped working :-( I'll update my question with that info. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. That's a shame. I don't know for sure if installing from a Windows 7 ISO will wipe the recovery partition. I've only ever reinstalled my Windows 7 from the recovery disks I made when I bought my Sony VAIO laptop after a HD failure. That recreated a recreated a recovery partition (as it restores to factory).

Comment: Installing W7 will break (overwrite) the custom MBR that links function keys to the recovery partition, so it will no longer be accessible, sometimes you can mark the recovery partition as "active" and reboot, it may load the Vaio recovery software then.